# sync specific texts to an audio in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, synchronization, subtitle

I am trying to show some texts as a summary of an audio file in flutter (Mobile Application). I need to display at specific time of audio, some texts. And when the user press the forward/backward button of audio to any second, specific texts should be display according to that time of audio.
I don't need to display exactly of the audio content as a text in screen.**(not like a subtitle)**
how can we display a specific Text at specific time of the audio in flutter?

Can you please give me any clue about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to show how one could approach something like this. The package used is [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).

```
class AudioTextSync extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioTextSync({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AudioTextSyncState createState() => _AudioTextSyncState();
}

class _AudioTextSyncState extends State<AudioTextSync> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  final texts = {
    3: 'Hi',
    7: 'How are you?',
    12: 'Bye',
  };
  static const maximumDisplayTime = 1;
  var displayText = '';
  var lastShownSecond = -maximumDisplayTime - 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(displayText),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _playOrPause,
                child: const Text('Play/Pause'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _init() async {
    player.onAudioPositionChanged.listen(
      (event) {
        final text = texts[event.inSeconds];
        if (text != null) {
          setState(() {
            displayText = text;
            lastShownSecond = event.inSeconds;
          });
        } else if (event.inSeconds - lastShownSecond >= maximumDisplayTime) {
          setState(() {
            displayText = '';
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  _playOrPause() async {
    if (player.state == PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      await player.pause();
    } else {
      await player.play("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3");
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially you have a map or an array of texts and times they should be displayed. I've used a map where each key and value is the time in second and the text that should be displayed. Then you add a listener to position change of audio and if it reaches a certain time where a text should be displayed you set the `displayText` to that. Also `maximumDisplayTime` here is set to 1 second and `lastShowSecond` keeps track of when the last text was displayed. If a longer time that `maximumDisplayTime` has passed since `lastShowSecond`, the `displayText` will be reset.

Comment: really appreciate your help, Ramin.